# getting the coordinates of the boundary of a 3d region

Tags: graphics, regions, mesh

I recently meet a problem of finding the points on the boundary of a 3D object, e.g., the points on a cylinder below:

```
a1 = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1];Graphics3D[a1]
```

I'm going to work on some more complex objects, which is to be obtained by ImplicitRegion, but I guess the process should be similar.

My question is, I'd like to get a list of the boundaries points similar to what we will get in a discretization method. E.g., if I use the spherical coordinates, I may discretize the two angles and calculate the corresponding radius, or if I use the Cartesian coordinates, I may discretize z and x then seeking for the corresponding y.

So how do I get such a list of data? I prefer to get the 3D list if possible. And how do I set the desired accuracy, like the increment I set in the discretization method? My wild guess is to generate a mesh on it, e.g. using the DiscretizeRegion, but I'm not sure if it is going to work or how. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say "the points"... well, of course there is an infinite number of points on the boundary of your cylinder.  What do you *really* want?  And why?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, hi, what I mean is a list of points, that are similar to what I would obtain via a discretization method, as I described in the problem. and I would like to be able to control how the points are distributed, like I discrete the x and z values with fixed increment, and find the corresponding  y, and I preferably I'd like to get a 3D list of dimension n_z*n_x*3 instead of a 2D list of  (n_z*n_x)*3. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first discretize the boundary of the region with `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, and then get the points with `MeshCoordinates`, like so:

```
ClearAll[cyl, its, trans];

cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, 1];
pts = MeshCoordinates@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@cyl;

ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: points]

Comment: Hi, this is basically what I'm looking for, but if possible, I'd like to be able to control how the points are distributed, like I discrete the x and z values with fixed increment and specify their values then find the corresponding  y.  Do you know how to control such things? Preferably I'd like to get a 3D list of dimension n_z*n_x*3 instead of a 2D list.  I guess it's probably  an option of BoundaryDiscretizeRegion,  e.g., the MeshCellShapeFunction or the Method? And it would be great if I could do it both in Cartesian and Spherical coordinates. Thanks.